# exception while executing groovy script from jenkinsfile groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: args for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to execute "myGroovyScript.groovy" from a jenkinsfile which is running at a remote server. Groovy script is kept in a path in server (not checked in scm). But I am getting exception. Is there a better way to do if I checkin the groovy script in github in same repo where jenkinsfile is also there.

I have a jenkinsfile as below

```
node('abcd'){

        def buildInput;

      echo 'Deploying build'
     if(!params.buildName) {
         buildInput = input(
                          id: 'userInput', message: 'What is the build name?', parameters: [
                          [$class: 'TextParameterDefinition', defaultValue: 'BuildNameIsABC', description: 'Environment', name: 'buildName']
                          ])
      }
      buildToUse = params.buildName ? params.buildName : buildInput;
      echo ("Env: "+buildToUse);

      if ( "${params.buildParam}" == 'prequal' || !params.buildParam ){

        stage('Prequal') {
                echo 'Checking prequal status for my product build'
            def rootDir = '/home/pathToGroovyScript'
            def example = load "${rootDir}myGroovyScript.groovy"
}
```

I am trying to execute "myGroovyScript.groovy" from above jenkinsfile. Groovy script is as below

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
def maxAttempt = 90
def attempt = 1
def frontDoorUrl
def waitTimeMS = 10000
def uiNodes
def service = args[0]
def uiNodesReady = false
def uiFrontDoorReady = false


//init important data in regards to the service
if ("abcd".equalsIgnoreCase(service)) {
    println 'Init config for service abcd'
    frontDoorUrl = "http://myFrontDoorURL"
    uiNodes = ["http://myUINodes"]
}

//ping nodes <service>
while (attempt <= maxAttempt && uiNodesReady == false) {
    println 'Attempt #' + attempt
    for (i = 0; i < uiNodes.size(); i++) {
        def result = ('curl -m 2 --write-out "%{http_code}" ' + uiNodes[i]).execute().text
        println 'UI node: ' + i + ' ::: ' + uiNodes[i] + ' status: ' + result
        if (result.contains("<StatusCode>200</StatusCode>")) {
            uiNodesReady = true
        } else {
            uiNodesReady = false
            break
        }
    }
}
```

I am running my jenkinsfile in remote linux server and after running it gives below stack trace. could you please help whats the problem. Sorry for long post.

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: args for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:224)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$4.call(Checker.java:241)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:238)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:28)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:8)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor513.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:173)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:162)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
```

Comment: looks like an issue with the sandbox - try running it not in the sandbox or go to the script approvals and approve any pending scripts

Comment: I believe there is something wrong I am doing where I am calling "myGroovyScript.groovy" from the jenkins file. That groovy script takes an argument, which I am not passing while calling the script. I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that in `myGroovyScript.groovy` you use `def service = args[0]` but `args` variable is not defined anywhere.
You can define it as a global variable in Jenkinsfile this way

```
//...
args = ['abcd'] //note you have to define it without def to make it global
def example = load "${rootDir}myGroovyScript.groovy" 
//...
```

But using global variables is error prone and not recommended. The better way would be wrapping `myGroovyScript.groovy` into function and then call it and pass service as parameter. Something like this
`myGroovyScript.groovy`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def execute(service) {
    def maxAttempt = 90
    def attempt = 1
    def frontDoorUrl
    def waitTimeMS = 10000
    def uiNodes
    def uiNodesReady = false
    def uiFrontDoorReady = false

    // all code go into function and ramain the same
}
return this // you also need to return a reference to this script
```

And then in Jenkinsfile

```
def example = load "${rootDir}myGroovyScript.groovy"
example.execute('abc')
```